# Componente Redirect no cambia la ruta en la barra de navegacion y tampoco renderiza el componente

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Estoy usando react-router y redux junto, cuando actualizo el estado del store. El componente no se vuelve a renderizar, y por ello, el Redirect no funciona.

Aqui esta mi codigo.

Este componente switch lo coloco en un `BrowserRouter`

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import React from "react"
import Login from "../pages/login"
import SignUp from "../pages/sign-up"
import ConfirmPhone from "../pages/confirm-number"

function AuthRoutes(props) {
    
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/confirmPhone">
                <ConfirmPhone />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default AuthRoutes
```

En la pagina `Login` luego de que se manda el código de verificación debo cargar el componente `ConfirmPhone` redireccionando al usuario a la ruta `/confirmPhone`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import M from 'materialize-css';
import Header from "../components/header"
import Button from "../../../components/Button"
import Dialog from "../../../components/Dialog"
import InputText from "../../../components/TextInput"
import truncateString from "../lib/truncateString"
import { onTextChange, onSubmitForm, onSubmitConfirm, openDialogOnLogIn } from "../config/ui-events"
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { selectAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "../actions/authSlice"
import { actions } from "../actions/authSlice"



function Login(props) {
    const [phoneField, setPhoneField] = useState('')
    const [valid, setValid] = useState(2)
    const openDialog = false
    const currentAuth = useSelector(selectAuth)
    const { signInWithPhoneNumber } = actions
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    function onChangePhone(evt) {
        const inputValue = evt.target.value
        setPhoneField(truncateString(inputValue, 8))
        setValid(onTextChange(evt, inputValue, /\d{8}?/))
    }

    function onSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()

        dispatch(signInWithPhoneNumber({ status: 2, session: null }))
    }

    if (currentAuth.status === 2) {
        console.log(currentAuth)
        return (<Redirect to="/confirmPhone" />)
    } else {

        return (
            <section className="login">
                <div className="login__layout">
                    <Header>
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                    </Header>
                    <form>
                        <p>Accede a tu cuenta</p>
                        <InputText id="phone-number"
                            pattern="\d{8}"
                            errorMessage="Incorrect phone format for +505 area code"
                            successMessage="The phone format is correct"
                            helperMessage="Type a phone number of +505 area code"
                            labelText="Telefono"
                            changeHandler={onChangePhone}
                            validationState={valid}
                            value={phoneField} />
                        <div>
                            <Button clickHandler={onSubmit} text="Entrar" classes="login__signIn" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="recaptcha-container" className="login__captcha">

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }

}

export default Login
```

cuando el campo status del estado cambia a 2, necesito hacer una re-dirección en lugar de cargar el componente  `Login` otra vez.

Pero aunque cambie el estado, el componente ni siquiera se vuelve a renderizar.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a ver que sucede?

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    value: {
      status: 0
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    signInWithPhoneNumber: (state, action) => {
      alert("authentication will update the store")
      state.auth = action.payload
    }
  },
});
```

la función reducer `signInWithPhoneNumber` es la que utilizo para actualizar el estado.

Se que debes de crear un objeto inmutable nuevo para actualizar el estado, en este caso no, porque según leí redux usa una librería que usa el objeto `Proxy` para encargarse de que los estados sean inmutables. Proxy escucha cuando una propiedad del state cambia y procede a crear una copia de todo el estado, agregando solo los cambios a esta copia. así cada estado esta inmutable.

Comment: ¿`selectAuth` cambia de estatus cuando aplicas `dispatch(signInWithPhoneNumber({ status: 2, session: null }))`? Saludos

Comment: Si, así es, cuando ejecuto dispatch para llamar al reducer, cambia el status.

Comment: El reducer recibe state, y action, hay otro detalle, el state que me da como argumento no es el state del store, es un objeto Proxy que no esta observando a ningun objeto...la verdad ya estoy muy confundido

Comment: Y por observar nada me refiero a que el target tiene como valor null, al igual que la funcion que se supone controla el acceso a las propiedades del objeto

Comment: Estoy usando Redux devtools, y el estado si se actualiza y pasa a ser el objeto con {session: null,status:2}

Comment: En la funcion reducer `signInWithPhoneNumber`, en vez de `state.auth = action.payload`, usa `state.status = action.payload`. Luego en `Login` usa `const currentAuth = useSelector(state => state.status)` avisanos si funciona, saludos.

Comment: Además, en `Login` intenta también cambiar el dispatch `dispatch(signInWithPhoneNumber(2))`